# Installing a C header on Linux/POSIX systems

Tags: c, linux, header, posix

I have a header `foo.h` with functions `bar()`, `baz()`, `qux()`. Where would I copy it/what would I have to do it so that I can include it in C programs like other systemwide headers, like stdio.h, unistd.h etc?

Comment: `/usr/include` is the default location for system headers. But you can use the `-I` option when compiling to specify other directories to search. You generally shouldn't modify the system directories like this.

Comment: `/usr/local/include` is a common place to put headers that are local to the current system. That is what it is for—for the system administrator to put headers to be shared by all users of the system. Nonetheless, you should be judicious about what you put there. Executing `cpp -v /dev/null -o /dev/null` may show you a list of paths that are searched for headers. (It shows a lot of output; look for the line `#include <...> search starts here:` and see the list after it.)

Comment: Generally speaking, I would advise to use a build system like Automake to generate a lot of useful boilerplate for you. If you would define `include_HEADERS = foo.h`, then whoever compiles and installs your software would be able to install it in the place of their preference, defaulting to `/usr/local/include` where it generally should be. s

Answer (score 1):

From [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/cpp/Search-Path.html) (I am assuming you are using GCC since you included the **Linux** tag):

> #### 2.3 Search Path
>
> GCC looks in several different places for headers. On a normal Unix system, if you do not instruct it otherwise, it will look for headers requested with #include  in:
>
> /usr/local/include
> *libdir*/gcc/*target*/*version*/include
> /usr/*target*/include
> /usr/include
>
> [...] In the above, target is the canonical name of the system GCC was configured to compile code for; often but not always the same as the canonical name of the system it runs on. version is the version of GCC in use.

So that mostly answers your question. But really, you probably shouldn't be putting non-system headers in places like `/usr/include`. Most of the time, it's best to keep the headers for your program in the `include` sub-directory for the project. Then tell GCC how to find those files like this:

> You can add to this list with the `-Idir` command line option. All the directories named by `-I` are searched, in left-to-right order, before the default directories. The only exception is when `dir` is already searched by default. In this case, the option is ignored and the search order for system directories remains unchanged.
>
> [...]

Also keep in mind the differences between `#include "file.h"` and `#include <file.h>`

> GCC looks for headers requested with `#include "file"` first in the directory containing the current file, then in the directories as specified by `-iquote` options, then in the same places it would have looked for a header requested with angle brackets. For example, if `/usr/include/sys/stat.h` contains `#include "types.h"`, GCC looks for `types.h` first in `/usr/include/sys`, then in its usual search path.
> [...]